# How to save user data when they log in using firebase authentication?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase Authentication to allow users to log into my Angular app.

Below is the `login()` method in my `AuthService`:

```
login(email: string, password: string) {
   return from(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password));
}
```

This is working fine, but now I am trying to store the user's data when they log in, so that they're not accidentally logged out when they refresh the app.

Can someone please tell me how I can use the object returned in the above method to ensure a user remains logged in unless they choose to log out of the app?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` then the user will stay logged in. You can check if the user is null or not by using:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

If user is signed in ,then just direct the user to the pages after login.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if I sign in with `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, & refresh the page, I'm not logged out? 
If that's the case, what could I add to my `canLoad` guard that I'm trying to use to validate if a user is logged in?
I tried to use your code above, but the error is `A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value
`

Comment: Did the answer help you? How are you using it in `canLoad`?

Comment: Hi, yes it did. I'm updating my question with the new code

Comment: After the user logs in with the firebase method, I'm trying to store their data in local storage, & then use that data in the `canLoad` guard

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist the data.
Look this doc:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence